# understand strongloop process manager deploy

Tags: strongloop

following the strongloop controler 'slc', 'process manager' documents, I have some questions for it.

as deploying to process manager with command like

```
slc deploy http://process.manager.url:7777 deploy_branch
```

we can specify process manager url. and I can deploy my package/source to remote for sure.
but I don't see any access control on deploying it. what if someone else try to push their package to mine?
Do I have to just deploy it locally and block the port from remote? then what the url for if we have to do it local only?
please help me understand if I don't get it right.

and one more thing.
I can deploy it twice like below commands,

```
slc deploy http://process.manager.url:7777 deploy_branch
```

and

```
slc deploy http://process.manager.url:7777/another deploy_branch
```

when the commands executed, I see process manager's repo directory has two git repos according to commands, **default.git** and **another/default.git**.
and slc pmctrl status shows **'config: another/default'** or **'config: default'** ...
so I just guess I can change active deployed package to another/default or default as process manager keeps them separated. but I don't know how and can't find any mention about it.
If repos are not for switchable resources, why does pm keep them in separated repo?

please help me understand these.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is really old but seeing as how I had a similar question and I now know the answer to at least one of your questions I thought I would post:

> what if someone else try to push their package to mine? Do I have to just deploy it locally and block the port from remote?

According to the documentation: https://github.com/strongloop/strong-pm

> Basic authentication can be enabled for HTTP by setting the STRONGLOOP_PM_HTTP_AUTH environment variable to : (eg. strong-pm:super-secret). This is the same format as used by the --http-auth option of pm-install.